# Update neo4j gui in real time from .net environment

Tags: c#, neo4j, neo4jclient

I am new to developing in Neo4j. I am trying to create and update all of the data in c# (using neo4jclient) as shown in the code below:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string username = "neo4j";
        string password = "password";
        try
        {
            var client = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://" + username + ":" + password + "@localhost:7474/db/data"));
            client.Connect();

            var newUser = new User { Id = 456, Name = "Jim" };
            client.Cypher
                .Create("(user:User {newUser})")
                .WithParam("newUser", newUser)
                .ExecuteWithoutResults();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.Write(e.Message);
            throw;
        }
    }

    public class User
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
```

So this connects to the neo4j client and adds a user. 
Then in the neo4j gui I can query this with:

```
MATCH (user:User)
RETURN user
```

And I get this as the result:
[image]

What I would like to do is to execute some code in the client part in c# and have it automatically update and display on the gui.

Is this possible and if so how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know much about C#/.NET but as far as I know this is generally not possible. You can't interact much with the neo4j browser or pass queries with URL parameters.

If you want to develop your own visualization have a look at http://sigmajs.org/ and http://graphalchemist.github.io/Alchemy/#/